# distinct items in IEnumerable object

Tags: c#

I am working with C# and have an `IEnumerable` object. Note(`IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>`)

How can I find the distinct items in that object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx), then [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)

```
var distinctItems = items.Cast<object>().Distinct();
```

Comment: Does this use the `Equals` method on the objects, or just compare by ref?

Comment: it uses the default comparator for those objects, there's an override on Distinct to provide your own `IEqualityComparer`

Comment: @p.s.w.g: `GetHashCode` is not used to determine if two objects in the collections are equal (thus not distinct). Two non-equal objects can have the same hash code. Eluvatar's comment is correct.

Comment: @MartinLiversage You're correct. I was inspecting the code and misread one line. It calls `IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals` to determine if the items are indeed equal. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @MartinLiversage If two instances give distinct hash codes, while they _are_ "equal" according to `object.Equals(object)`, the `Distinct` method will (with high probability) yield both of them. So if `GetHashCode` is broken, `Distinct` method will give unpredictable results.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It evidently uses `GetHashCode` to try to make the `Distinct` work faster, but ultimately uses `Equals` to determine distinctness. Although I suppose this could probably still break if you override `GetHashCode` to return a different value for two items that otherwise would be considered equal by `Distinct`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g If you made such an override of GetHashCode, it would violate the method's requirements.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx, which says "If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must return the same value."

Comment: @Eluvatar to answer Polynomial's question, it uses the default equality comparer for `System.Object`, which in turn calls the Equals method.

Comment: @Polynomial It does call the Equals method, by invoking the default equality comparer.  If the objects in question do not have an override of the Equals method, of course, the comparison will be a reference comparison.

Comment: @p.s.w.g to elaborate: To find if an object is a duplicate, the method first looks for already-encountered objects with the same hash code.  Then it checks each of these objects for actual equality.  If GetHashCode returns a different value for two objects, the first step will fail, and the fact that the item is a duplicate will be missed.  (This description of the algorithm is slightly simplified -- it really searches for hash codes that are equal modulo some prime number, but the principle holds: the hash code is used to eliminate most objects, reducing the number of calls to Equals.)

Comment: @phoog The modulo stuff was why I wrote "with high probability" in a parenthesis in my comment. The two instance have to give equal hash code _modulo_ the prime currently used by the hash table. Since we can't know what modulus (number of buckets) it's currently using, we'd better give really identical hashes (modulo `Int32`).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen of course.  The parenthetical part of my comment was just to acknowledge that, for the purpose of explanation, I was describing a simplified version of the algorithm.  The fact that the actual hash table algorithm would succeed in some very small number of cases, where the one I described would not, as you note, doesn't imply that a broken hash code is any less broken.  A stopped clock is right twice a day, while a clock that gains a second every day is right only once every 43,200 days.